# How to switch in tabs of popup

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[enter image [enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJT86.png)description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIQAu.png) hi when i give details and click on button one popup appears which is having two tabs how to switch between those tabs?

```
Util.NavigateToLoginPage(ref Driver);
            HomeWf.Login(Driver, Username, Password);
            var homePage = new PrimaryNavigation(Driver);
            homePage.ClickOnMainNavigators(Driver, MainNavigation.Products);
            homePage.ClickOnSubMenuOptions(Driver, SubMenuLinks.Products.AddNewProduct);
            var bulndlepage = new ProductHomePage(Driver);
            bulndlepage.LnkBundleProduct.Click();
            //bulndlepage.TxtBrowseNode.SendKeys("Mobile Phones");
             bulndlepage.SelectCategory(Driver, "Books"
            Console.WriteLine("TxtTitle PRINTED");
            bulndlepage.TxtSku.SendKeys("6701");
            Console.WriteLine("TxtSku PRINTED");
            bulndlepage.ChkCod.Click();
            Console.WriteLine("ChkCod PRINTE
            bulndlepage.ChkOffline.Click();
            Console.WriteLine("ChkOffline PRINTED");
            bulndlepage.BtnSaveNext.Click();
            bulndlepage.BtnSaveNext.Click();
            bulndlepage.BtnAssociateProd.Click();
           Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stock your first window name and your popup name.

```
//Click on your PopUp
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[id*='IdElemToCLick']")).Click();

string LastWindow = null;
string FirstWindow = null;

foreach (var item in driver.WindowHandles)
{
    //Stock first window name
    if (FirstWindow == null)
    {
        FirstWindow = item;
    }
    LastWindow = item;
}

if (LastWindow != null)
{
    // Go to PopUp
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(LastWindow);
    // Do something with this PopUp
    [...]
    // Go back to Main Page
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(FirstWindow);

}
```

Comment: hi, when i click on button the popup appears...so why to take css selector of popup and click that @Jeflow

Comment: I HAVE ADDED THE IMAGE LINK CAN YOU SEE ONCE @jeflow

Comment: @DevyaniM Hi ! The CssSelector is only an other solution to find an element by its ID, but I use this method because you can find by partial ID of an element (In my case, most of the Element's ID are auto generated and can change between two differents machines).

Comment: I have Tried this code but its not working. Can you see the image ad help me if u can? @Jeflow

Answer (score 0):

I see the window appears is a Modal window. You can simply get the id/cssSelector/xpath of the tabs and click on them as required.

Comment: Hi,I tried for that also driver.FindElement.(By.Id).Click() but it says that the id not found i tried for id xpath css still same.And if i sendkeys in the title textbox then also it say textbox id not found. @optimist_creeper